# Updating UILabel in Child View 1 after Global Variable Update in Child View 2

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uilabel, containers

I have made a simple app to test this and cannot figure it out. I have an iPad storyboard where I have put two container views as shown below. I have a label in one view and a button in another. My button will increment the label, 1 number at a time.

My problem is not passing the value or incrementing, but getting the view to load the new value.
Each container has its own ViewController

Some code below, although very sparse as Ive written a bunch and deleted as it didn't work. Please help with the correct format. I would like to keep this general format, updating global variable within button and it updating the label.

```
LabelViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LabelViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *checkLabel;

-(void)loadLabel;

@end
```

---

```
LabelViewController.m
#import "LabelViewController.h"
#import "ParentViewController.h"

@interface LabelViewController ()

@end

@implementation LabelViewController
@synthesize checkLabel;
-(void)loadLabel{
    checkLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",value];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self loadLabel];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

---

```
ButtonViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface ButtonViewController : UIViewController
- (IBAction)checkButton:(id)sender;
@end
```

---

```
ButtonViewController.m
#import "ButtonViewController.h"
#import "ParentViewController.h"
#import "LabelViewController.h"

@interface ButtonViewController ()

@end

@implementation ButtonViewController
- (IBAction)checkButton:(id)sender {
    value++;
    NSLog(@"%d",value);
    LabelViewController *fnc = [[LabelViewController alloc] init];
    [fnc loadLabel];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Picture at:
http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3822/9469907420_746db25b23_b.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ButtonViewController, you don't want to be alloc init'ing an instance of LabelViewController -- the one that's on screen already exists. Both child view controllers are instantiated just before the parent controller is. So, what you need to do is get a reference to the LabelViewController that's on screen. You can do that with self.parentViewController.childViewControllers[0] (that 0 might have to be 1 -- I don't know which controller is which).

```
 LabelViewController *fnc = self.parentViewController.childViewControllers[0];
 [fnc loadLabel];
```

Comment: ahhh PERFECT. I had started this but must have been mixing things. thanks so much. works great!!